# pip install Module Error on Mac OSX 10.10.2

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am trying to install `ipython` using `pip`.

```
sudo pip install ipython
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/functools.py", line 67, in <module>
    ('__lt__', lambda self, other: not self >= other)]
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/_functools.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/_functools.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'resource_filename'
```

Previously when I encountered this problem, re-installing `functools` fixed the problem.

Howver this time I cannot even use:

```
pip list
```

Is `functools` broken again?

Comment: sorry for bother, this problem is fixed, it's multiple python version problem.

Comment: I remove the python with brew uninstall python, the problem fixed..